# Terraform: Windows cloud-init is unable to provision files from Parameter Store

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, terraform, cloud-init

I have this configuration where I get files from AWS SSM Parameter Store and save them

```
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "certificate" {
  name = "/project/certificate"
}
    
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "private" {
  name = "/project/private"
}
    
data "aws_ssm_parameter" "config" {
  name = "/project/config"
}
    
data "cloudinit_config" "userdata" {
  gzip          = false
  base64_encode = false
    
  part {
    filename     = "init.ps1"
    content_type = "text/x-shellscript"
    content      = file("${path.module}/scripts/init.ps1")
  }

  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content = yamlencode({
      write_files = [
        {
           content     = data.aws_ssm_parameter.certificate.value
           path        = "C:\\aws-iot-device-client\\certs\\certificate.pem.crt"
           permissions = "0744"
        },
        {
           content     = data.aws_ssm_parameter.private.value
           path        = "C:\\aws-iot-device-client\\certs\\private.pem.key"
           permissions = "0744"
        },
        {
           content     = data.aws_ssm_parameter.config.value
           path        = "C:\\aws-iot-device-client\\aws-iot-device-client.conf"
           permissions = "0744"
        },
      ]
    })
  }
}
    
resource "aws_instance" "win_device_agent_ec2" {
  ami                  = var.ec2_ami
  subnet_id            = var.ec2_network
  key_name             = var.ec2_ssh_key
  instance_type        = var.instance_type
  iam_instance_profile = var.ec2_iam_role
    
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
     var.ec2_sg,
  ]
    
  user_data = data.cloudinit_config.userdata.rendered
    
  tags = {
     Name = var.instance_name
  }
}
```

The issue is that powershell script init.ps1 works fine, but second part with cloud-config is not working.
Trying to understand what is missing and why the values are not being picked up and stored.
Tested on linux, works fine.

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: no errors in C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2Launch\log\agent.log

Comment: Hm, ok, does the role have permissions to pull the information from the SSM Parameter Store?

Comment: @MarkoE yes it does, and it works ok with linux(mentioned it). the issue is with windows, I am trying to understand what is missing in the config

Comment: Could it be that the Linux AMI has something installed that Windows AMI does not?

Answer (score 0):

> but second part with cloud-config is not working. Trying to understand what is missing and why the values are not being picked up and stored. Tested on linux, works fine.

cloud-init supports [many different operating systems](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/distros.html), but **not Windows**. Do not expect cloud-init userdata to work on Windows.

Comment: I see that similar setup works for people [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63041528/cloud-init-i-am-trying-to-copy-files-to-windows-ec2-instance-through-cloud-ini) the only difference is that i get the data from parameter store

Comment: @Murad - Take a look at cloudbase-init. That's probably what is being used in that example. Cloud-init definitely does not support Windows, and the project has no intention to do so.